# GetIntentExtra() Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, get

I'm trying to do a simple app using TheMovieDB api.
In my app I have an activity where it shows all the films with a specific word.
If the user clicks in one film I want to start a new activity that shows some information like overview, title, logo of the film . . .

TheMovieDB has some standard methods, like search by id or search with a specific word.

When the app shows all the films with the word "hello" for example, how can I capture the id of a film that the user clicked and do the "search by id" methods and print all the information in a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dettagli_film` is an Activity than you can do this

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //string id_film = "" + id;  
    var id_film = dati.ElementAt(e.Position).filmId; // select your fildId here
    Intent myIntent= new Intent (this, typeof(dettagli_film));  
    myIntent.PutExtra("key", id_film);
    StartActivity (myIntent);
    Toast.MakeText(this, id_film, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Now in `OnCreate` of new `dettagli_film` activity get data

```
var data = Intent.GetStringExtra("Key");
```